# how to add image to iOS firebase remote notification

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, apple-push-notifications

the scenario that I am trying to achieve is that when the iOS app is closed, the remote firebase notification with an image should popup,the image can be in place of the app logo or a bigger image can open on user tap.
I am successfully getting the notification but I dont know how to add an image into it.I am guessing I"ll have to override the `UNUserNotificationCenter`functionalities and add something to the payload like

```
{
  "priority":"high",
 "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "body": "5 to 1",
    "icon": "my desired image"
  },
   "to": "ebBUO1R..."
}
```

I'd be glad if anyone can point me towards the right direction or any help(preferably in swift).
Regards